# Animation lags when using other UI elements

Tags: c#, wpf

On the form placed a line that rotates at a low speed of 1 revolution per 10 seconds. When i am run the application animation is good. but when I use any other element of the interface (click button textbox) drawing a line begins laggs. What could be the problem?

I am make a radar. Line should be rotated with high accuracy. And i am should know angle of line that handle collisions.

i use timer

```
  int razvlineAngle = 0;
  RotateTransform rotateTransform1 = new RotateTransform(0, 384, 384);

 private void ShowTick()
    {

            razvlineAngle++;
            rotateTransform1.Angle = razvlineAngle;
            razvline.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1; 

}
```

Comment: How do you rotate the line? With code, a transform? Please post the relevant code

Comment: I use a timer, code in added in post

Comment: Don't. If you already have a transform, just change its values, don't recreate a new one. Second, you can specify that a transform value should change periodically simply using XAML, using StoryBoards and Triggers

Comment: i am tried, code in post. It not help me

Comment: if im add rectangle to form and use event MouseLeftButtonUp animation is good, but when i press button animation begins lagging.

Comment: @user3215282 what button? what does the button do? post the full code.

Comment: i am adding buttons without events, and when i am push it animations begin lagging

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rotate a line in pure XAML using a DoubleAnimation and a RotateTransform eg:

```
<Canvas>
   <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="300"  Y2="100"  Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="Black"     OpacityMask="Black"  >
        <Line.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="50"/>
        </Line.RenderTransform>
        <Line.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Line.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                         To="-360" 
                                         Duration="0:0:1" 
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
</Canvas>
```

This doesn't require any timers. DoubleAnimation changes its target property from its original value to its `To` in the timespan specified by `Duration`.

You can achieve the same effect with code. In this case the Line XAML is simply:

```
    <Line x:Name="MyLine"  X1="0" Y1="0" X2="300"  Y2="100"  Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="Black" OpacityMask="Black"  />
```

and the code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, -360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        {
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
        };

        var transform = new RotateTransform(0,150,50);
        MyLine.RenderTransform=transform;

        transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
    }
```

You don't need a timer because DoubleAnimation provides timing. You also don't need to create a new RotateTransform nor set the line's RenderTransform for each step. Changes to the transform's Angle property automatically cause the line to render

Please note that transforms occur on the UI thread. If you perform heavy processing on your button events the animation will still be blocky. The way to fix this is to perform heavy processing on the background, eg using Tasks or a background thread

Comment: i am need high accuracy in rotate, and i use winmm.dll timer. When i am using Dispatcher.Timer line have time error 4 sec on minute. Your code can provide this accuracy?

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with all the relevant information.

Comment: sorry, i am want say "question"

Comment: if i easily  press on textBox animation begin lagging